# Unable to add event listener for MouseWheelZoom event in Openlayer map

Tags: angular, openlayers, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

I am trying to implement a functionality using openlayers with Angular in which I have to add one interaction using MouseWheelZoom.

Interaction gets added but control does not come inside the event listener for this when I move my mouse wheel in map.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createMap();
    const mapInteraction = new MouseWheelZoom();
    this.map.addInteraction(mapInteraction);
    mapInteraction.on('change', (event) => {
      console.log('event', event);
    });
  }

  createMap() {
    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
      }),
    });
  }
}
```

Please find a simple stackblitz for this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-openlayers-demo-6ozx4p?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: If you call `mapInteraction.changed();` the event fires as expected.  MouseWheelZoom is included in the default interactions, you do not need to add another one.

Comment: Do  I need to add the interaction in this way ?

`code`
import Interaction from 'ol/interaction/Interaction';
const mapInteraction = new Interaction();
    this.map.addInteraction(mapInteraction);
    mapInteraction.changed();
    mapInteraction.on('change', (event) => {
      console.log('event', event);
    });

Comment: @Mike calling "changed" method would trigger the event manually, but we want to listen to the event when its triggered by user interaction

Comment: Before adding a customised interaction you must exclude the default when you create the map `nteractions: defaultInteractions({mouseWheelZoom: false}),`  The interaction does not fire change events in response to user actions, it causes the view to fire a `change:resolution` event.

Comment: The interaction does not fire change events in response to user actions, it causes the view to fire a `change:resolution event` 
Yes you are right on this

Comment: The interaction does not fire change events in response to user actions, it causes the view to fire a `change:resolution event` 
Yes you are right on this point 
But if we add or remove the `interactions: defaultInteractions({mouseWheelZoom: false}),` from map creation it does not give any output in user action response.
Also if you see  I am using` map.getview().on('change:resolution, ())` which is giving me resolution change but here we are not getting specific event type whether it is a wheel event or touch pad event.
So my purpose is not resolved yet.

Comment: @Mike  `ngOnInit() {
    this.createMap();
    const mapInteraction = new MouseWheelZoom();
    this.map.addInteraction(mapInteraction);
    this.map.getView().on('change:resolution', (event) => {
      console.log('event', event);
    });
  }

  createMap() {
    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      interactions: defaultInteractions({ mouseWheelZoom: false }),
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM(),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
      }),
    });`

Comment: This event is fired not only in mouse wheel touch pad pinch & zoom case but also in case when we are changing the zoom in out from action button

Comment: @Mike, you said "The interaction does not fire change events in response to user actions, it causes the view to fire a change:resolution event". But the **change:resolution** event fires also when users zoom using control buttons. I want to perform some action only when user zooms using mouse wheel or pinch. How can I detect that?

Comment: You could intercept the event in a custom condition function for the interaction https://codesandbox.io/s/mousewheelzoom-vpo66c?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike Thanks a lot. It was quite helpful. I tried to do the same with PinchZoom, but it didn't allow me to override "condition". Any suggestions how we can get a callback for user-triggered ZoomPinch?